# Why has nationalism risen in Switzerland?

Tags: nationalism, switzerland

According to [this article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-36130006) nationalist and far-right parties have made significant electoral gains during the last elections. I will focus on Switzerland that is highlighted with almost 30% on the map, due to [Swiss People's Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_People's_Party#Party_strength_over_time), which gained 29.4%.

According to the same Wikipedia article, the party votes (%) have risen more than double (from 11% about 45 years ago).

**Question:** Why has nationalism risen so much in Switzerland in the last decades?

Comment: The party you mentioned had a sharp rise in the 1980s and 1990s and since 2008 it had actually be loosing votes, so I don't think it's a good example. Besides, this question is very board.

Comment: a) what's "far-right" today was pretty average 30-40 years ago, so these attributions are difficult b) are there polls saying that people voted for SVP because of nationalism and not other positions / disappointment with other options?

Comment: @Bregalad - according to 2015 the party had received the highest number of votes (%) in the monitored period. Also, my question is related to the number of votes of a single party within a single country - any suggestion how can I narrow down the scope of the question?

Comment: @Alexei Considering that Switzerland is a single country makes as much sense as considering that the European Union is a single country... Each canton has its specificities, and the SVP is very different depending on the cantons. Also, your first link just compares % of votes of specific parties which have few things in common among different countries. It ranges from controversial trolling right-wing parties such as the SVP to violent extreme-right parties such as Golden Dawn, which have few in common.

Comment: What Sweden considers far-right now, other countries may consider left leaning